# Unparseable Date at offset 5

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I am having trouble trying to convert the string `Mon, 01 Feb 2016 13:04:51 -0500` to a date.

Using

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);`

or `Locale.ENGLISH` brings up a parse exception with this in the logs:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 01 Feb 2016 13:04:51 -0500" (at offset 5)`

How can i convert it to a date?

Comment: check my answer , you can even remove last Z too !!

Comment: It's a typo question which won't help future searchers, and which should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Change this line from

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
```